# Lambda handler function callback is returning only 10 items from the response object here as there are 29 in the array which are being logged

Tags: aws-lambda, callback

Api is not returning all the results in the response. It is only returning 10 elements where as there is no limit applied on the query and I get all the items shown when I check the logs in cloudwatch

```
finally{
         conB.end();
         callback(null, Response);
       }
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide more information about the handler code, which language, how do you output the query result vs Response here in the code snippet

Comment: Hi tsamaya, thans for responding back. Actually there was a typo in the code which was causing the unusual behavior of the callback.